# Shouldn't the compiler be able to deduce the template arguments from the concept?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-argument-deduction, c++-concepts

In the following piece of code, shouldn't the compiler be able to deduce the template argument from the concept?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Bar;

template<typename F, typename T>
concept Foo = requires (F foo, Bar<T> bar)
{
    { foo.test(bar) } -> std::same_as<T>;
};

template<typename T>
struct Bar
{
    T value;

    template<Foo<T> F>
    T test(F foo)
    {
        return foo.test(*this);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct FooBar
{
    T value;

    T test(Bar<T> bar)
    {
        return (value = bar.value) + bar.value;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Bar<float> b{ 1 };
    std::cout << b.test(FooBar{}) << std::endl; // Fails to deduce the template argument
    std::cout << b.test(FooBar<float>{}) << std::endl; // Compiles successfully
}
```

Is this a feature that's not been implemented by MSVC and GCC (both fail at compiling the code) yet? Or is it just invalid C++20 code? If so, why is it? Isn't `float` the only possible type for the template argument `T`? Or is there some alternative that I'm missing and that can cause ambiguity for the compiler?

Comment: It would be nice if you let us know what the error message is, and where it occurs.

Answer (score 2):

From what exactly is the compiler going to deduce the template argument to `FooBar{}`? You provided no arguments, and there are no special class template deduction guides, and the template `FooBar` has no default template parameters.

If you're expecting template deduction to happen by the *use* of an expression, rather than from the innate properties of the expression itself (arguments in the initializer, default template parameters), then that is the wrong expectation.

Class template argument deduction is based *entirely* on the arguments provided to the initializer of the class object, just as function template argument deduction is based entirely on the arguments provided to the function. How either expression gets used thereafter is irrelevant.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I don't know why, but I was convinced that template deduction could be done just by the use of an expression. It still bugs me that that's something the compiler isn't capable of (or that it's still not a c++ feature), because in a lot of situations there's no ambiguity and the compiler should be able to determine it, right? Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In this case the compiler will not deduce the type as, at the point of use, a concrete (non-generic) type must be defined for a template type.

**Default Template Argument**

In the example code provided, at the point that where the compiler complains, `FooBar{}` is lacking the concrete type definition, like `FooBar<SomeType>`, as you know.

This syntax `FooBar{}` would've worked with a default template argument though, like so:

```
template<typename T=float> // <-- Add a default concrete type, now it compiles and runs
struct FooBar
...
```

**Value Type Alias**

Another alternative would be creating an alias at the point of use capturing a generic value_type and subsequently applying it to the templates.

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar
{
    using value_type = T; // <-- Allows capturing the value_type after the 'point of use' definition.

    T value;

    template<Foo<T> F>
    T test(F foo)
    {
        return foo.test(*this);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    using V = Bar<float>::value_type; 

    Bar<V> b{ 1 };
    std::cout << b.test(FooBar<V>{}) << std::endl; // Compiles successfully
    std::cout << b.test(FooBar<V>{}) << std::endl; // Compiles successfully
}
```

This is interesting because in a sense, a function receiving a generic object can *peek* at that object's value_type and *forward* it while instantiating new generic objects.

The `concept` definition seems to be correct, as given the following code:

```
Bar<float> b;
b.test(FooBar<int>{});
```

The compiler issues the following message while testing:

> error C7602: 'Bar::test': the associated constraints are not satisfied

Which is as expected according to the logic implemented by the concept.

**Summary**

- As FooBar is a template and which has not relation at all with the fact that Bar is also a template, it still needs its own type to be specified at the point of use or alternatively a default value_type can be specified for the template argument.
- A value_type of a generic object can actually be captured after the point of use with an alias and applied while defining other generic objects.

**Reference**

I found the section 6 on *Templates* and 7.5 on *Template Compilation Model* of *A Tour of C++* by Bjarne Stroustrup to be very informative on these topics and may also give you further insight.

**Note**

For those willing to enable C++20 Preview Features in Visual Studio 2019, go to:

`Project > YourProjectName Properties > C/C++ > Language > C/C++ Language Standard`

And select:

`Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft(/std:c++latest)`